# React Native Lottie - Progress animation using state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, after-effects, lottie

I am using `react-native` to build the mobile Application. Moreover, I am using `lottie` to show an animation (filling water glass). (Image is attached).

[image]

In the application there is a button and when that is clicked  a glass will be filled 1/4 (this can vary) of the glass and next time it will fill the other 1/4 of the glass and so on. I was able to do that using following code snippet. But what I want do is after 1/4 of water filling the water level should be a straight line. (last stage of the animation) But in following code it's 1/4 of the animation. I am using `adobe after effect` to create the animation. So can any one suggest me a solution for this.

```
class Screen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 0,
      progress: new Animated.Value(0),
    };
  }

  handlePress = () => {
    this.setState({value: this.state.value + 0.2}, () =>
      Animated.timing(this.state.progress, {
        toValue: this.state.value,
        duration: 1500,
        easing: Easing.linear,
      }).start(),
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text>History</Text>
        <Button
          title="Press"
          onPress={() => {
            this.handlePress();
          }}></Button>
        <LottieView
          source={require('../../assets/7731-water-loading.json')}
          progress={this.state.progress}
          loop={false}
          autoPlay
          autoSize
          style={{width: 400}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```